# Play a different sound on second, third, etc clicks of an element

Tags: javascript

I have an element that plays a 'thank you for voting' sound when you click it, as you can only vote once I need to add a second sound which is something like 'you cannot vote twice!'. How would I edit this code to add the second sound for any future clicks?

```
<script>
var klaxon = new Audio ();
klaxon.src = "https://thebookmachine.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/klaxon.mp3";
</script>



<div class="poll" onmousedown="klaxon.play()">
[Total_Soft_Poll id="2"]
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable that tracks the number of clicks and then have a function that updates the source of the audio before playing it if the number of clicks exceeds your threshold.

```html
<script>
const klaxon = new Audio ();
let numClicks = 0
const f = () => {
  numClicks++;
  if (numClicks < 2) {
    klaxon.src = "https://thebookmachine.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/klaxon.mp3";
  } else {
    klaxon.src = "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3"
  }
  klaxon.play()
}

</script>



<div class="poll" onmousedown="f()">
[Total_Soft_Poll id="2"]
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your help, that's really helped me out :)

Comment: glad I could help! If you wouldn't mind accepting my answer, I'd appreciate the little reputation boost :)

Comment: of course, where do you click 'accept'? I know I am pushing my luck but is there a way of editing that script so if you click to a new page on the website and then back again it will play the second sound? Until the website is reloaded really

Comment: you could achieve that using localStorage or sessionStorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage